# Sorting xml nodes in groovy

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, groovy, nodelist

I have an XML, to which I need to add new nodes, which I have achieved using appendNode. However, the newly added node is put at the end of the XML. I would like to now sort this XML so that it goes to the correct position:

```
<Order>
<Customer>
...
</Customer>
<item>
    <itemID>1</itemID>
</item>
<item>
    <parentItemID>1</parentItemID>
    <priority>25</priority>
</item>
<item>
     <itemID>2</itemID>
</item>
<deliverydetails>
</deliverydetails>
<invoiceTerms>
....
</invoiceTerms>

//this is my newly added item
<item>
    <parentItemID>2</parentItemID>
    <priority>35</priority>
</item>
</Order>
```

I need to reorder it so that it appears at the top like:

```
<Order>
<Customer>
...
</Customer>
<item>
    <itemID>1</itemID>
</item>
<item>
    <parentItemID>1</parentItemID>
    <priority>25</priority>
</item>
<item>
     <itemID>2</itemID>
</item>
<item>
    <parentItemID>2</parentItemID>
    <priority>35</priority>
</item>
<deliverydetails>
</deliverydetails>
<invoiceTerms>
....
</invoiceTerms>
</Order>
```

Tried the following Code:

```
Node root = new XmlParser().parse(xml);
def orderNode = root.Order;
....
orderNode[0].children().sort(true) {it.item.parentItemID.text()}
```

Comment: So you only want to sort the `<item>` documents?  And they have no parent?  They're just at the same level as `<deliverydetails>`, `<Customer>` and `<invoiceTerms>`?  Are there any other elements at root level?  Why `root.Order`?  Is `<Order>` inside another document you're not showing us?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I only need to put that last item node that I newly added so that it appears together with the other item nodes, rather than at the end (preferably together with the item ID specified under parentItemID so that items and their related sub-items are together). The Order node is the parent of the item node. There is only one Order node ..All the other nodes are under it. There are no other elements at the root level.  There is an element with a namespace that I omitted there.

Comment: The whole thing should be done via XSLT. It will take of both: (1) adding what is needed, and (2) sorting.

Comment: ok, first time using XSLT though. Appreciate a sample XSLT for doing that..thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I only need to put that last item node that I newly added so that it appears together with the other item nodes, rather than at the end (preferably together with the item ID specified under parentItemID so that items and their related sub-items are together)

If you are sure that an item with an `itemID` of 2 (your newly-added item's `parentItemID`) will appear in the input XML, you could do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item[itemID=2]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <item>
        <parentItemID>2</parentItemID>
        <priority>35</priority>
    </item>
</xsl:template>
        
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

***-- added --***

If you only want to reorder the nodes so that all `item` elements are kept together (after the new item has already been added), then you could do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Order">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Customer"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="item"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="deliverydetails"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="invoiceTerms"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you want to make sure that the newly added item comes after its parent item (or, more precisely, that *every* sub-item comes after its parent item), try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="sub-item" match="item" use="parentItemID" />

<xsl:template match="/Order">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Customer"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="item[not(parentItemID)]">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="key('sub-item', itemID)"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:copy-of select="deliverydetails"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="invoiceTerms"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks but now that I have added the element via groovy (it had some calculations to be done to arrive at the priority value that I have already done), it would be great if the current elements are just sorted. i.e get all the items to be together and it should be fine. Are you able to provide an updated version to just 'sort' my item elements and all other xml elements remaining at the same positions?

Comment: See if one of the added alternatives can work for you.

Comment: P.S. IMHO, it might be simpler to pass the calculated values to the stylesheet as parameters and let it add the new item based on those.

Comment: Thanks, Is there something that can specify 'copy everything except item nodes' ? Then copy item nodes? Because I actually have around 35 other nodes...(like Customer etc) which I have not mentioned in the question as it was not relevant....:( So I will have to use that initial copy of for the remaining nodes one by one.

Comment: Well, yes: you could use `<xsl:copy-of select="*[not(self::item)]"/>` (or,  if your processor supports XSLT 2.0, `<xsl:copy-of select="* except item"/>`). But then they will all appear before (or after) the block of `item`s, instead of "remaining at the same positions" as you have requested.

Comment: Thank you! I have changed it with the select * except item for now and it works for the requirement.